# Finding each 3 subset of closest coordinates (lan and long), Python

Tags: python, dataframe, geospatial

I have data set of bike sharing. The data has lan and long for each station. A sample of data is like below. I want to find each 3 station that are close to each other in term of coordinate and sum up the count for each of subcategory (3 closest points).

I know how we can calculate the distance between two point. but I don't know how to program this, in term of finding each 3 subset of closest coordinates.

The code for calculating distance between 2 point:

```
from math import cos, asin, sqrt, pi

def distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    p = pi/180
    a = 0.5 - cos((lat2-lat1)*p)/2 + cos(lat1*p) * cos(lat2*p) * (1-cos((lon2-lon1)*p))/2
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a))
```

The data :

```
    start_station_name  start_station_latitude  start_station_longitude. count
0   Schous plass                59.920259       10.760629.                 2
1   Pilestredet                 59.926224       10.729625.                 4
2   Kirkeveien                  59.933558       10.726426.                 8
3   Hans Nielsen Hauges plass   59.939244       10.774319.                 0
4   Fredensborg                 59.920995       10.750358.                 8
5   Marienlyst                  59.932454       10.721769.                 9
6   Sofienbergparken nord       59.923229       10.766171.                 3
7   Stensparken                 59.927140       10.730981.                 4
8   Vålerenga                   59.908576       10.786856.                 6
9   Schous plass trikkestopp    59.920728       10.759486.                 5
10  Griffenfeldts gate          59.933703       10.751930.                 4
11  Hallénparken                59.931530       10.762169.                 8
12  Alexander Kiellands Plass   59.928058       10.751397.                 3
13  Uranienborgparken           59.922485       10.720896.                 2
14  Sommerfrydhagen             59.911453       10.776072                  1
15  Vestkanttorvet              59.924403       10.713069.                 8
16  Bislettgata                 59.923834       10.734638                  9
17  Biskop Gunnerus' gate       59.912334       10.752292                  1
18  Botanisk Hage sør           59.915282       10.769620                  1
19  Hydroparken.                59.914145       10.715505                  1
20  Bøkkerveien                 59.927375       10.796015                  1
```

what I want is :

```
closest                                   count_sum


Schous plass, Pilestredet, Kirkeveien.      14
.
.
.
```

```
The Error: 



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-1a4d3a72c23d> in <module>
      7     for idx_1, idx_2 in [(0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2)]:
      8         total_distance += distance(
----> 9             combination[idx_1]['start_station_latitude'],
     10             combination[idx_1]['start_station_longitude'],
     11             combination[idx_2]['start_station_latitude'],

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try all possible combinations with [itertools.combinations()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and save station pairs with shortest total distance.

```
from itertools import combinations

best = (float('inf'), None)

for combination in combinations(data, 3):
    total_distance = 0
    for idx_1, idx_2 in [(0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2)]:
        total_distance += distance(
            combination[idx_1]['start_station_latitude'], 
            combination[idx_1]['start_station_longitude'], 
            combination[idx_2]['start_station_latitude'], 
            combination[idx_2]['start_station_longitude'], 
        )

    if total_distance < best[0]:
        best = (total_distance, combination)

print(f'Best combination is {best[1]}, total distance: {best[0]}')
```

---

Keep in mind that there's still room for optimization, for example caching distance between two stations like

```
lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    p = pi/180
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, How can I solve this error? string indices must be integers

Comment: Did you see my comment?

Comment: you need to do some tweaks with joining `combinations` and `data`, you could create combinations of data indexes like `combinations(range(len(data)), 3):` and then define `combination = [data[idx] for idx in combination]`

Comment: I would be grateful if you can update the answer. sorry I am new to python..

Comment: I think there should be a change for the     for idx_1, idx_2 in [(0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2)]:
also

Comment: could you please update your original question with full traceback?

Comment: I did, but I also I want the list of all tree combination , maybe this line just go through the first 3 row:  for idx_1, idx_2 in [(0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2)]:

Comment: Hi Filip DID YOU SEE TH ERROR?

Comment: add `combination = [data[idx] for idx in combination]` at beginning of the loop or change `combinations(data, 3)` to `combinations(data.values(), 3)`